# Replace hashes of hash with another hashes of hash

Tags: perl, hash, replace, key

I have two hash of hashes that I created from two separate tex file. I wan to change the value of second hashes of hash with the first hashes of hash and want to write it in third file. or I can replace the value in second text file it self.

File1:

```
family (){
kapoor(){
member1(){
male(){
between : 0 to 5
person : 2
their name is bla & bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}

male(){
between : 5 to 5
person : 20
their name is bla & bla bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}
}

member2(){
male(){
between : 0 to 5
person : 2
their name is bla & bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}

male(){
between : 5 to 5
person : 20
their name is bla & bla bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}
}
}


rai(){
member1(){
male(){
between : 0 to 5
person : 2
their name is bla & bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}

male(){
between : 5 to 5
person : 20
their name is bla & bla bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}
}

member2(){
male(){
between : 0 to 5
person : 2
their name is bla & bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}

male(){
between : 5 to 5
person : 20
their name is bla & bla bla. 
and bla bla......
blaa.....
}
}
}
```

hash1:

```
family=>{

     kapoor => {
                member1=>{ 
                           0 to 5=> person : 2
                                    their name is bla & bla. 
                                    and bla bla......
                                    blaa.....

                          }   
               member2=> {
                          5 to 5 => person : 20
                                    their name is bla & bla bla. 
                                    and bla bla......
                                    blaa.....

                }

rai =>{
/...................etc
}
```

hash 2 is same but value is different.

I tried:

```
while(my$line=<$fh>)  ******** to store hashes of hash from file 1***
  {

  if($line=~/$family_name_re/)
  {
      $family_name=$1;
  $family_count=$cell_count+1;
  }
  elsif ($line=~/$member_re/)
  {
  $member = $1;
 }
  elsif ($line=~/$age_re/)
 {
  $age_range=$1;

 push @{$data{$family_name}{$member}{$age_range}{values}},$line;
  }
}
  print Dumper(\%data);
  print "Number of cell is $cell_count\n";

 close ($fh);
```

same way I am reading from second file and storing it in hashes of hash 2.

Any suggestion how I can replace the value? 
I tried to replace in second file but it didn't work.

```
$_=~s/$newvalue/$data{$family_name}{$member}{$age_range}/;
```

Instead of replacing, I think to write file2 as it is in third file and only value from first file get reflect in third file.

Comment: What happened with your RegEx? Did you get the correct value (for example via `print`)?

Comment: Yes. I am getting correct values in both hashes of hash

Answer (score 0):

You already said that you get correct values using your RegEx, so just write them back to a file:

```
open my $fh3,'>','file3.txt';
print $fh3 "family (){\n";
for my $family (keys %data) {
    print $fh3 "$family () {\n";
    for my $member (keys %{$data{$family_name}}) {
        print $fh3 "$member () {\n";
        for my $age_range (keys %{$data{$family_name}}) {
            print $fh3 "$age_range () {\n".
                  join(
                      "\n",
                      @{$data{family_name}->{$member}->{$age_range}->{values}}
                  ).
                  "}\n";
        }
        print $fh3 "}\n";
    }
    print $fh3 "}\n";
}
print $fh3 "}\n";
```

Loop through all levels of the structure printing everything to the file.

Another attempt:

```
sub write_part {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $data = shift;

    if (ref($data) eq 'HASH') {
        for my $key (keys %$data) {
            print $fh "$key () {\n";
            write_part($fh, $data->{$key});
            print $fh "}\n";
        }
    } elsif (ref($data) eq 'ARRAY') {
        print $fh join("\n", @$data)."\n";
    } else {
        print $fh $data."\n";
    }
}

open my $fh3, '>', 'file3.txt';
write_part($fh3, \%data);
close $fh3;
```

The sub is called once passing the topmost data structure and calls itself whenever it gets a HashRef as `$data`.

Comment: This will just write hashes of hash as it is. I want to replace value of file2 from file1. I have two such hashes of hash. This will print only values stored in hashes of hash not the lines  other than stored in hashes of hash  gets printed.  I tried this logic..I keep printing file2 as it is in file3 until I found the values. When I found the value then It will search for related values in first hashes of hash and print it in file3.